# Regex pattern in java

Tags: java, regex

What would be a regex pattern for the following  '   and ® in Java.  I have tried the following but have not been successful

1. `&#[0-1][0-1][0-1]`
2. `&#\d\d`

Comment: Can you include some examples of the strings that you want to match? I really can't understand what you need.

Comment: did you try Pattern.compile(String regex) on a plain string containing your characters?

Comment: public class TestException {
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    String str = "This is chili&#39; restaurant";
       
      try
      {
       checkSpecialCharacters(str);   
      }
      catch (SpecialCharactersException se)  
      {
        System.out.println("Spell exception was: " + se.getError());
      }
}
  public static void checkSpecialCharacters(String str) throws SpecialCharactersException
   {
   if (str.matches("&#39;")
     {
    throw new SpecialCharactersException();
     }
     else
     {
       System.out.println("ok");
     }
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, then it should be:

```
str.matches(".*&#\\d{1,3};.*");
```

This matches &# followed by 1, 2 or 3 digits and then a ;)

Comment: well, I would like to match 50 or 60 of these special encodings. The general pattern is &#digit digit digit; So I need a generalized regex pattern.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason it is not matching. I am using Eclipse. The \d gives me an error.

Comment: You need to escape it, use \\d in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

These should work:

1. `".*\\x27.*"`   matches an embedded apostrophe
2. `".*\\xae.*"`    matches an embedded registered trademark symbol

I tested with String.match

If you need longer unicode values you can use

1. `".*\\u0027.*"`   matches an embedded apostrophe
2. `".*\\u00ae.*"`    matches an embedded registered trademark symbol

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html